# Is it possible to upload mongodb files with my ASP.NET MVC website on a host?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mongodb, installation, host

This may be strange, but is it possible to upload `mongodb` application files to my `ASP.NET MVC` host and use them in only my website without any setup and installation?

[updated]

**I'm not a administrator on host. I'm just a normal user with privileges of uploading my ASP.NET MVC project files using file manager.**

[/updated]

If it's possible so how? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to uploading the files you will also have to install a MongoDB instance to connect to. If you are not an administrator you will unlikely have the necessary privileges to start the MongoDB process which will listen on the default port 27017.

Comment: Is it possible to use it like `SqlCompactEdition`? Do you know any NoSql database without installation requirement?

Comment: @Jalal Amini, embedded databases such as `SqlCompactEdition` are intended to be run on client applications such as mobile devices, desktop applications, during development and unit testing but not in production environments of web applications which might require high scalability. In those environments it is recommended to use databases which are specifically designed for this purpose.

Comment: @Jalal Amini, Windows has a built in embedded database called [ESENT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2008/10/23/esent-extensible-storage-engine-api-in-the-windows-sdk.aspx) which is used by RavenDB. It has a [managed wrapper available](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/). Most NoSQL databases that I know require a service to run and listen on a TCP port. You can specify this port, so you could probably ask the administrators run such database. For example RavenDB could be hosted as a Windows Service.